# Unable to loop over object after ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I know that this question is already asked but I could not find answer for what I want.

I am trying to loop over data that I get in `JSON data` format after `ajax` response.
my Javascript Code is:

```
function ajaxMe(){
    $(function(){
      $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : 's-test.php'
      }).done(function(data){
        values = [data];
        alert(data)
      })
    });
  }
```

After receiving the data in `values` variable successfully I am trying to print it using `console.log(JSON.stringify(values))`  in `console` and this gives result as:

```
["\r\n  {\"lat\" : \"51.508742\", \"ln\" : \"-0.320850\" , \"name\" : \"my corporation\"},\r\n  {\"lat\" : \"51.508742\", \"ln\" : \"-0.420850\" , \"name\" : \"my corporation\"},\r\n  {\"lat\" : \"51.508742\", \"ln\" : \"-0.520850\" , \"name\" : \"my corporation\"},\r\n  {\"lat\" : \"51.508742\", \"ln\" : \"-0.620850\" , \"name\" : \"my corporation\"},\r\n  {\"lat\" : \"51.508742\", \"ln\" : \"-0.720850\" , \"name\" : \"my corporation\"},\r\n  {\"lat\" : \"51.508742\", \"ln\" : \"-0.820850\" , \"name\" : \"my corporation\"},\r\n  {\"lat\" : \"51.508742\", \"ln\" : \"-0.920850\" , \"name\" : \"my corporation\"},\r\n  {\"lat\" : \"51.508742\", \"ln\" : \"-1.320850\" , \"name\" : \"my corporation\"},\r\n  {\"lat\" : \"51.508742\", \"ln\" : \"-2.320850\" , \"name\" : \"my corporation\"},\r\n  {\"lat\" : \"51.508742\", \"ln\" : \"-3.320850\" , \"name\" : \"my corporation\"}\r\n"]
```

instead of

```
[{"lat" : "51.508742", "ln" : "-0.320850" , "name" : "my corporation"},
  {"lat" : "51.508742", "ln" : "-0.420850" , "name" : "my corporation"},
  {"lat" : "51.508742", "ln" : "-0.520850" , "name" : "my corporation"},
  {"lat" : "51.508742", "ln" : "-0.620850" , "name" : "my corporation"},
  {"lat" : "51.508742", "ln" : "-0.720850" , "name" : "my corporation"},
  {"lat" : "51.508742", "ln" : "-0.820850" , "name" : "my corporation"},
  {"lat" : "51.508742", "ln" : "-0.920850" , "name" : "my corporation"},
  {"lat" : "51.508742", "ln" : "-1.320850" , "name" : "my corporation"},
  {"lat" : "51.508742", "ln" : "-2.320850" , "name" : "my corporation"},
  {"lat" : "51.508742", "ln" : "-3.320850" , "name" : "my corporation"}]
```

And unable to loop over this `object` when using `forEach` :

```
values.forEach(function(v, i){
    alert(i);
});
```

How it can work.?
Thank you.

Comment: You are conveting the `data` to `string`. Try to use `JSON.parse(data)` to get the `JSON` object back.

Comment: If that is your data, looks like you server is not returning the data right

Comment: Another victim of the inexplicable `JSON.stringify` trend. Nowadays, we are flooded with people who convert a data structure (JSON) into a linear chain of characters (string) and then don't understand why they can't see their data structure anymore. I just can't explain how everyone got to do that.

Comment: instead of `JSON.stringify` I am unable to loop over the data and when I loop over the data it run only once and return whole object instead of running one by one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all add a simple line to your jquery ajax code 
`dataType: 'json'`

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 's-test.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {               
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {                     
                alert(value.lat);
            });               
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
function ajaxMe(){  
  $.ajax({
    method:"GET",
    url : 's-test.php',
    success:function(data){
      var obj = $.parseJSON(data);        
      $.each(obj, function (key, value){                     
          alert(value.lat);
          alert(value.ln);
          alert(value.name);
      });
    }
  });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you echo the data from the PHP script, use json_encode(your data). This will return a JSON object. Then in the AJAX request set the 'dataType: "json"'. You will then be able to use console.log(data).

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : 's-test.php'
    dataType: 'json',
  }).done(function(data){
    values = [data];
    alert(data)
  })
```

You will then be able to use a for loop to loop through the results like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.legnth; i++){
    console.log(data[i]);
}
```

[json_encode() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)